# Copy boost dependencies in CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Tags: boost, cmake, copy

I've this `CMakeFiles.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1.0)
project (wfractal-test)
include(CTest)
enable_testing()

set (CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/export/bin)
set (CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

find_package (Boost 1.58.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)

include_directories (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
file (GLOB TEST_SOURCES "*.cpp")
add_executable(wfractal-test ${TEST_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries (wfractal-test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(wfractal-test fractal)

add_test (NAME wfractal-test COMMAND wfractal-test)
set_property(TARGET wfractal-test PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
set_property(TARGET wfractal-test PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
```

I want to copy all boost libraries used in `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` inside the CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY where I put my program because at the moment my executable does not find `boost_unit_test_framework-vc140-mt-gd-1_60.dll` and I want to avoid to copy it by giving manually the full name, because in this case the name changes if I change compiler or boost version, and because if I add some other dependencies I can be able to copy automatically all of them without change the code.

How can I copy all boost libraries that I specify with `COMPONENTS` inside a custom folder?

Comment: `How can I copy all boost libraries that I specify with COMPONENTS inside a custom folder?` - Iterate over list ${Boost_LIBRARIES} and issue command for copy files. What is a problem with this approach?

Comment: In your case you are probably better off with linking Boost libraries statically. See [Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindBoost.html).

Comment: Rather than copying, you could add the directories to the debugging environment's PATH. In the VS I add this to my local debugging environment in each project: `PATH=$(SolutionDir)..\deps\bin;$(Path)` Saves a lot of copying and duplication of all the dlls.